# React select input as option

Tags: react-select

Im trying to create a generic Async React Select. 
At the moment my Select is showing Suggestions (using entered mail) which are loaded via external API. The user is forced to select a suggestion.
In Future I also want to provide an individual Input possibility, where the user can enter a own mail without selecting a suggestion. I cant find any solutions for these issue.
Any help would help me a lot.

My React Select (Type Async)

```
 export default class AsyncSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.loadOptions = this.loadOptions.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(selectedOption){
    this.setState({ selectedOption })
    if(this.props.onOptionSelect){
        this.props.onOptionSelect(selectedOption)
    }

  }

  loadOptions(input, callback) {
    this.props.loadOptions(input).then(options => {
      callback(null, {options: options})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <Select.Async
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
          isLoading={false}
          placeholder={this.props.label}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AsyncSelect.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
  loadOptions: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `Select.async` you could use the HOC provided by the lib `AsyncCreatable` that allows you to choose a suggestion OR create a new entry.

check the [readme](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#combining-async-and-creatable) of react-select for more details ;)

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I read over this section in the documentation. It seems to solve my problem.